# Is it possible to get a function's original returndata if it is wrapped in an interface that doesn't return anything?

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, assembly, returndata, returndatasize

Will a function's `returndata` persist through a wrapper, even if the wrapper does not support a return value? An example would be as follows:

```
contract OriginalContract {
    function originalFunction() external returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
interface originalContractInterface {
    function originalFunction() external;
}

contract MyContract {
    address originalContractAddress = 0x123...;

    function mainFunction() public {
        originalContractInterface(originalContractAddress).originalFunction();
        checkReturnData();
    }

    function checkReturnData() internal returns (uint256) {
        uint256 isReturnDataPresent = 0;

        assembly {

            switch returndatasize

            // No return data present
            case 0x0 {
                isReturnDataPresent := 0
            }

            // Return data present
            case 0x20 {
                isReturnDataPresent := 1
            }
        }

        return isReturnDataPresent;
    }
}
```

In the above example, will calling `mainFunction()` cause `checkReturnData()` to return a 0 or a 1? The `OriginalContractInterface` does not have a return value, so when `mainFunction()` calls it, will `checkReturnData()` be able to read the return value from the `originalFunction()` in the `OriginalContract`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `checkReturnData()` will be able to read the return data from `originalContractInterface` and will return `1`.

---

For context, `returndata` is the data returned from the last function call. `returndatasize` is the size of the return data from that call.

In the example given in the question, `mainFunction()` calls `originalFunction()`, which then sets the `returndata` that is used by `checkReturnData()`. This function now sees return data, so the switch case enters `case 0x20` and sets `isReturnDataPresent` to `1`.

> Will a function's `returndata` persist through a wrapper, even if the wrapper does not support a return value?

The question asks whether or not the `returndata` will persist, *even if the original function is wrapped in an interface that does not return anything*. In the code block, `originalContractInterface` has an interface for `originalFunction()`, **but does not include the same return value that the original function does**. Even in this scenario, the `returndata` will persist, because it has already been written to the `returndata` slot in memory and has not been written over by anything.

---

To provide further clarity (using the same code as above for reference), the following interfaces would *always* store the same `returndata`:

```
interface originalContractInterfaceWithoutReturn {
    function originalFunction() external;
}

interface originalContractInterfaceWithReturn {
    function originalFunction() external returns (uint256);
}
```